# how to pass prop into rowrender of react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm trying to render a card list with react-virtualized. The posts data on this particular component is passed as a prop from the parent. This is what I currently have in my component class.

```
state = {
    listHeight: 1000,
    listRowHeight: 800,
    listRowWidth: 1000,
    rowCount: 10
}


rowRenderer ({ index, key, style, posts }) {
    if (!posts) {
        return <div></div>
    } else {
    return (
        <PostItem key={key} style={style} post={posts[index]}/>
    );
    }
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <div id="postListContainer" className="ui relaxed list">
                <List 
                    width={this.state.listRowWidth}
                    height={this.state.listHeight}
                    rowHeight={this.state.listRowHeight}
                    rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                    rowCount={this.state.rowCount}
                    posts={this.props.posts}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I hardcoded the rowCount since I know I have 10 items in my posts array currently. Just for context, this was my original code that renders the entire list successfully.

```
renderPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map(post => {
        return (
            <PostItem key={post._id} post={post}/>
        );
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <div id="postListContainer" className="ui relaxed list">
                {this.renderPosts()}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue i'm currently having is that I can't access the props passed down into this component from my rowRenderer function so it gives me an undefined error. So my question is, how do I access the posts props in the rowRenderer function? I'm just trying to return a PostItem component for each post in the posts prop array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `rowRenderer` looks like this:

```
function rowRenderer ({
  index,       // Index of row
  isScrolling, // The List is currently being scrolled
  isVisible,   // This row is visible within the List (eg it is not an overscanned row)
  key,         // Unique key within array of rendered rows
  parent,      // Reference to the parent List (instance)
  style        // Style object to be applied to row (to position it);
               // This must be passed through to the rendered row element.
}) { .. }
```

So you don't get access to the props through the arguments. You can access the props via the instance variable, `this`.

You should bind your handler when you pass it into `List` like this:

```
<List 
    ...
    rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer.bind(this)}
/>
```

then inside of `rowRenderer` you can simpy access `this.props.posts`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties sent from List tag in  rowRenderer method using parent  that is received in rowRenderer.Checkout signature [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md)

```
rowRenderer ({ index, key, style, parent }) {
 const posts = parent.props.posts; 
 if (!posts) {
    return <div></div>
 } else {
    return (
      <PostItem key={key} style={style} post={posts[index]}/>
    );
 }
}
```

That should solve your problem.Also you can access props either by binding this variable to rowrenderer method or by ES6 syntax

```
 rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, parent }) => {
 const posts = parent.props.posts;
 const { someThing } = this.props; 
 if (!posts) {
    return <div></div>
 } else {
    return (
      <PostItem key={key} style={style} post={posts[index]}/>
    );
 }
}
```